# how to change inbox messages mark from unread to read

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a inbox messaging system. All my messages are appearing unread, when most should be marked as 'read'. I have it set in my messages model to check if unread or read. So I'm not understanding why the code is not working for unread/read.

message.rb:

```
belongs_to :sender,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
belongs_to :recepient,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'recepient_id'

    def mark_message_deleted(id,user_id)
        self.sender_deleted = true if self.sender_id == user_id and self.id=id
        self.recepient_deleted = true if self.recepient_id == user_id and self.id=id
        self.sender_deleted && self.recepient_deleted ? self.destroy : save!
    end

    # Read message and if it is read by recepient then mark it is read
    def self.readingmessage(id, reader)
        message = find(id, :conditions => ["sender_id = ? OR recepient_id = ?", reader, reader])
        if message.read_at.nil? && (message.recepient.user_id==reader)
            message.read_at = Time.now
            message.save!
        end
        message
    end

    # Based on if a message has been read by it's recepient returns true or false.
    def read?
        self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
    end

    def self.received_by(user)
       where(:recepient_id => user.id)
     end

     def self.not_recepient_deleted
       where("recepient_deleted = ?", false)
     end

end
```

messages controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archieved"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:reply_to]
      @reply_to = User.find_by_user_id(params[:reply_to])
      unless @reply_to.nil?
        @message.recepient_id = @reply_to.user_id
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender_id = @user_id
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  end

  def delete_multiple
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(id)
          @message.mark_message_deleted(@message.id,@user_id) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = current_user
    end
end
```

index view:

```
<h2>Your Inbox</h2>
<% if @messages.size == 0 %>
No messages in your Inbox
<% end %>
<% else %>
        <%= form_tag delete_multiple_user_messages_path, :method=>:post do %>
            <table  class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Delete?</th>
                    <th>Sent</th>
                    <th>Sender</th>
                    <th>Sent</th>
                </tr>
                    <% for message in @messages %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= check_box_tag "delete[]", message.id %></td>
                            <td>
                                <% if message.read? %>
                                  <%= link_to h(message.subject), user_message_path(@user, message) %>
                                <% else %>
                                  <%= link_to "#{h(message.subject)} (unread)", user_message_path(@user, message) %>
                                <% end %>
                            </td>

                            <td><%=h message.created_at.to_s(:long) %></td>
                        </tr>
            <% end %>
            </table>
        <%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %> |
        <% end %>
<%= link_to "Compose New Message", new_user_message_path(@user)%> | 
<%= link_to "View Sent Messages", user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox => :sent)%>
```

Comment: can you put your controller action also?

Comment: and can you add where you are calling all the methods like `readingmessage`

Comment: I added the inbox view. I was thinking I just needed to have it in the model. Do I have to add code to the view template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your messsages are all appearing as unread because the `read_at` field is never changed from`nil`.

It looks like your `readingmessage` method is supposed to change the value, but it's never called.

(It would make sense to call it in the `show` method in your controller.)

Model:

```
def readingmessage
  self.read_at ||= Time.now
  save
end
```

Controller:

```
  def show
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    @message.readingmessage if @message.recipient == current_user
  end
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how to call that in the controller, as I haven't done something similar to that before. Also not understanding why I would have to def something in model, and then also def that same method in the controller.

Comment: Messages are still mark as unread. Perhaps it has something to do with the views template for inbox.

Comment: The only reason it would be left marked as unread would be if the current user isn't actually the recipient, or you're not actually viewing the message with the `show` action.  The code's too simple to be wrong.

Comment: Well as of now the inbox is open to the public. In the from I can place any ID there, but I don't have it set to each ID has it's own inbox yet. So that could be the reason for the unread issue. I will keep code and once I have the other part implemented, I will come back to this question to answer if it work or not.

Comment: Code now works as I had to fix some other things. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

This method is doing too much:

```
# Read message and if it is read by recepient then mark it is read
def self.readingmessage(id, reader)
    message = find(id, :conditions => ["sender_id = ? OR recepient_id = ?", reader, reader])
    if message.read_at.nil? && (message.recepient.user_id==reader)
        message.read_at = Time.now
        message.save!
    end
    message
end
```

I don't understand why you're calling this method when the sender is reading the message, but if that's what you need, I'd go for something like:

```
# Read message and if it is read by recepient then mark it is read
def self.readingmessage(id, reader)
    message = find(id, :conditions => ["sender_id = ? OR recepient_id = ?", reader, reader])
    message
end

def self.mark_read(id, reader)
      # Read message and if it is read by recepient then mark it is read
    def self.readingmessage(id, reader)
        message = find(id, :conditions => [recepient_id = ? and not null read_at", reader])
        if message
            message.read_at = Time.now
            message.save!
        end
        message
    end
end
```

I assume your controller/view knows when the recipient is reading a message and the id of the message in question, in which case `mark_read` can be simplified considerably

Comment: I have to examine your code more to understand what you're trying to do. And it breaks down the app anyways with "undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass". Will let you know what I come up with